# How can I test significance of 2 PCA results/PCA polygons

Tags: r, pca, biostatistics, climate

The story so far is that I am comparing the climate niche of wild native UK tree species, with the climate niche of commercial growers that grow that species in the UK. Using the species code 'agl' as an example, I've extracted the wild agl climate values and the commercial agl climate values for a number of points (11 climate factors, roughly a few thousand wild points and a few hundred commercial points). I've run a PCA on the wild values and then projected the commercial values onto those results. Through this I've managed to create some nice polygons showing the overlap of the commercial polygon on the wild polygon, and am able to say 'x% of the wild polygon is represented by the commercial polygon' (the commercial is always smaller). This has all been done in R no problem.

What I'm having trouble with is working out what test I can do to test whether there's a **significant difference** between the polygons.
Initially my project supervisor said that a PERMANOVA analysis would be most appropriate, but having looked into it and read a number of papers doing similar analyses I'm not 100% sure.
I've also read some stuff about k-means clustering but that doesn't seem to fit my data either.
I'm not very strong on maths or statistics due to dyscalculia, if PERMANOVA is the correct analysis for my data I'd really appreciate a simple explanation as to why. If another test is better I'd still love an explanation, but at least I'll have something more concrete to google and do my own research in.

### Extra details:

The wild and commercial climate data sets are saved as two separate data frames, but it wouldn't be difficult for me to merge them and assign a 'group' column of either 'wild' or 'commercial'

The PCA was done using prcomp NOT ade4 (which other similar papers I've read seem to use) and reduces dimensionality to 2

The wild and commercial PCA results are also saved separately from each other, however as the commercial was projected it looks very different (wild has 11 PC columns and 11 climate variable rows, commercial has 11 PC columns and 66 sampled points rows)

I have been able to calculate the areas of the individual polygons, as well as the area of overlap and % of wild polygon overlapped, if that helps at all with choosing a test

[image: This is my polygon output with the blue representing wild and orange representing the commercial projection]

This is my polygon output with the blue representing wild and orange representing the commercial projection

Comment: I suspect you can't test equality of the polygons, as these aren't model parameters but rather computed from the data. Would it be an appropriate null hypothesis for you that the distributions of wild and commercial are the same as far as can be assessed from these polygons?

Comment: Thinking about this a bit more, it is clear that the commercial polygons can be expected to be smaller, as the wild PCA *maximises* the variance along the first PC(s) for the wild data, whereas the first PC for the wild data will not normally maximise the variance for a different data set. This means that the commercial polygons may well be systematically smaller even if the two distributions are the same, so I don't think "significant differences in polygons" would have a meaningful interpretation. It could be different if you computed the PCA on wild and commercial data together.

Comment: Anyway I'm not quite sure what interpretation you have in mind for these polygons. Maybe you really want to test equality of distributions regardless of these polygons and maybe even of what the PCA shows?

Comment: @ChristianHennig I am wondering if performing the PCA on both at once might give better results, I found another CV question that talked about statistically testing two groups against each other

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/413299/what-do-ellipses-of-pca-analysis-factoextra-mean

Comment: I get concerned about the groups being independent, but the link I posted above should have the two groups fully independent like mine as far as I can tell. Assuming in the answer given I can say that traits = climate variables then it would let me test how different the groups are climatically.
The polygons themselves I think are more visual representations of any overlap the two groups have so that I can say 'this species is well represented in its bioclimatic envelope'

Comment: The other question you link seems to operate on PCs computed on the two groups together. This makes sense to me (if you compute PCs on one group and project the other one in, they are treated systematically differently in this way, which will induce meaningless differences), and the test recommended there may also apply.

Comment: I have like halfway to a fully formed thought which involves combining the Bootstrap with Jaccard distance between the two polygons. Are you familiar with either of these techniques, OP?

Comment: @JohnMadden I know Bootstrap as a concept, not heard of Jaccard before but I'll do some research!